# Почему не выводится результат?

Tags: python, requests, beautiful-soup

При запросе номера 79999999999, выводится 2 результата.
Но если на сайте результат всего 1, как в случае с 79062296890, то результат почему то не выводится.

```
phone_main = '79062296890'
epieos_url = 'https://tools.epieos.com/skype.php'
epieos_params = {'data':f'+{phone_main}'}

epieos_response = requests.post(epieos_url, data=epieos_params)
epieos_soup = BeautifulSoup(epieos_response.text, 'html5lib')

epieos_skype = epieos_soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'col-md-4 offset-md-4 mt-5 pt-3 border'})

skype_result_0 = ''
length=len(epieos_skype)
if length >=1: 
    skype_find_0 = epieos_skype[0].text.strip()
    skype_name_0 = skype_find_0.split('Id :')[0].strip()
    skype_name_0 = skype_name_0.replace("Name : ","")
    skype_name_0 = skype_name_0.replace("Skype","")
    skype_name_0 = skype_name_0.replace(">","»")
    skype_name_0 = skype_name_0.replace("<","«")
    skype_login_0 = skype_find_0.split('Id :')[1].strip()
    skype_result_0 = f'\n<b>Скайп:</b> <a href="https://transitapp.com/redirect.html?url=skype://{skype_login_0}?chat">{skype_login_0}</a> | {skype_name_0}'

skype_result_1 = ''
length=len(epieos_skype)
if length >=2: 
    skype_find_1 = epieos_skype[1].text.strip()
    skype_name_1 = skype_find_1.split('Id :')[0].strip()
    skype_name_1 = skype_name_1.replace("Name : ","")
    skype_name_1 = skype_name_1.replace("Skype","")
    skype_name_1 = skype_name_1.replace(">","»")
    skype_name_1 = skype_name_1.replace("<","«")
    skype_login_1 = skype_find_1.split('Id :')[1].strip()
    skype_result_1 = f'\n<b>Скайп:</b> <a href="https://transitapp.com/redirect.html?url=skype://{skype_login_1}?chat">{skype_login_1}</a> | {skype_name_1}'

# result
    text = f""
    if skype_result_0:
        text += f'{skype_result_0}'
    if skype_result_1:
        text += f'{skype_result_1}'
 
    print(text)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    if length >=1: 
        ...
    if length >=2: 
        ...
    # result
        text = f""
        if skype_result_0:
            text += f'{skype_result_0}'
        if skype_result_1:
            text += f'{skype_result_1}'

        print(text)
```

Отступы важны. Здесь у вас лишний отступ и весь код с формированием переменной `text` и её печатью попадает внутрь второго блока `if`, а он должен быть снаружи, судя по логике.  При этом комментарий `# result` стоит с правильным отступом, но он ни на что не влияет, комментарии интерпретатором просто пропускаются. Уберите лишний отступ:

```
    if length >=1: 
        ...
    if length >=2: 
        ...
    # result
    text = f""
    if skype_result_0:
        text += f'{skype_result_0}'
    if skype_result_1:
        text += f'{skype_result_1}'

    print(text)
```